# Why does webpack proxy do not work (Access-Control-Allow-Origin error)?

Tags: javascript, http, webpack, cors, axios

So, I am trying to bypass CORS on the server by proxying my requests. I am using webpack and axios.
So, here is webpack dev server options:

```
devServer: {
            contentBase: './build/',
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: true,
            quiet: true,
            open: false,
            port,
            noInfo: false,
            clientLogLevel: 'error',
            proxy: {
                '/api/**': {
                    target: 'http://mydev.com',
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    secure: false
                }
            }
        }
```

and axios:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://mydev.com',
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-AUTH-TOKEN':
            'my-token
    },
    data: {}
});
```

But still my origin is `localhost` and `option` request does not go through. Hence I am have this error.

Just to clarify: I want to make request from localhost to mydev.com with JSON content and bypass CORS settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack's proxy option actually creates a small reverse proxy server, which connects to your target endpoint.
In this case, your app (axios instance) should connect to your proxy:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'localhost:3000/api' // your local server here
    ...
});
```